# Consulta à partir de seleção em comboboxes

Tags: php, sql, combobox

Tenho 4 comboboxes populadas com dados de um banco, usando js. O usuário seleciona opções nessas 4 caixas e, a partir daí, eu quero fazer uma query com as opções escolhidas. Como posso pegar essas opções e guardá-las em variáveis pra usar na minha query?

Comment: Quando você diz "combobox" você quer dizer um `select` com vários `option`s, certo? Dar um `name` ao `select` e um `value` pra cada `option` faz com que o `value` desse `select` seja o valor do item selecionado. Aí você pode enviar como parte de um formulário ou - se estiver usando ajax - obtê-lo da mesma forma como pegaria o valor de qualquer elemento (ex.: `var valor = document.getElementById("meuSelect").value`).

Comment: Por exemplo, a primeira combobox é uma lista de cidades. As opções são preenchidas por um while com mysql_fetch_assoc.